# My PI 2 is stuck at boot

Tags: boot, raspbian-jessie

I am using a 3.5 inch TFT screen with my Raspberry Pi and jessie loads perfectly well.

When I connect my Pi to my LCD screen that it gets stuck at boot.

I have made the necessary changes in the config.txt as well to support LCD monitor but still the same. I read in some forums that using a more powerful charger can boost up the pi to load the OS but I'm afraid it might fry my Pi.

Answer (score 1):

A more power full power supply (PSU) can't fry the Raspberry Pi.

The current a PSU can deliver is depending on what your Raspberry Pi is consuming.

It's like drinking water from a glass, if you have a large glass you will not drink more water, you drink the water you can drink, independently of the size of the glass.

Comment: To complement this answer: more powerfull​ means more amps. More volts will fry your Pi.